# Increase django fixed value

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my Django project, there is a fixed number in one of the html input fields and I want this number to increase every time the form is opened. But since it will increase every time the form is opened, it is necessary to get the value of the last data from the database in that field. How can I apply something like this?

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example of how the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) that will change the value in database everytime anyone renders a template that includes base.html:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def raise_visit_counter():
    # here add +1 where you need and remember to use .save()
    return ""
```

and in base.html template:

```
{% raise_visit_counter %}
```